# flash message type :success appears as :error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

from controller I 'm sending flash message as

```
redirect_to admin_root_path,:flash => { :success => "Password Changed successfully" }
```

but when I try to check its type in layout using

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, type,class: "alert alert-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

It display its type as "error" while I passed type as "success"

whats going wrong with this?

Comment: <div class="alert alert-<%= type %> text-center"><%= message %></div> Use this

Comment: what are you trying to say???

Comment: you are assigning the wrong class to the content_tag. class assignment should be dynamic.

Comment: try this `<%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "alert alert-#{type}" %>`

Comment: Its displays flash message type's as "error" instead of success
I don't think that your comment has anything related to question

Comment: again same thing I am saying that it recognizing type as "error" while I passed it as "success"

Comment: Then there is must be anything wrong in the controller. Install `pry-rails` and debug.

Comment: @ProsenjitSaha's comment should be an _answer_ (not a comment) because it is the correct solution to this problem. Muhammad, try it and accept this community's help with a little humility. (Also, see Akshay's answer below, which is a more complete version of Prosenjit Saha's comment.)

Comment: I 'm not asking about dynamic thing, I 'm saying that it says that type is "error" while I passed type as "success"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this .................

```
<% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, type,class: "alert alert-#{type}" %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: ok 
but I 'm saying that when I try to see type of flash message it says its type is "error"
while  I passed it as "success"

Comment: Using binding pry or debugger check what are you getting in your flash. Is this the same hash passed by you `{ :success => "Password Changed successfully" }` or the other one?

Comment: Now you pointed me towards right direction
thats the issue man
thanks

Comment: I tried dynamic thing but displaying all messages with white background

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp Please have a look for alert classes of bootstrap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109694/discussion-between-akshay-and-muhammad-faisal-iqbal).